# Customizing the Places Bar in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, customization

Has anybody succeeded in customizing the Places Bar for VS 2008? My customizations from VS 2005 did not transfer to 2008 (obviously), and no matter what I do with the registry, I cannot make my custom places appear on the Open dialogs. I have read and applied the relevant MS KB article, to no avail.

This used to work fine with VS 2005, so it may well be a VS 2008 bug, but I may be wrong trying the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some observations:

VS2008 uses now Common File Dialog. With Powertoys TweakUK i was able to set all places to 'none' and the VS2008 'Open File' dialog becomes empty.

Unfortunately VS2008 ignores user defined places or directories, and shows instead the default places: 'Desktop', 'standard_project_folder', 'My Computer'.

With Sysinternals RegMon i see that Registry Key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\PlacesBar] gets read on ctrl+o...altough the places defined in here are still being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for checking this. To me it looks like a bug causing only minor annoyance, so no sweat, but still. I'll keep hunting.

Comment: OK, I accepted this now, in the knowledge that such customization will probably never again be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

VS2005 and VS2008 (sp1 anyway) both still use the following registry Key structure

**So, for vs2008, create these reg paths.**

> HKCU/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/9.0/Open
>   Find/Places/UserDefinedPlaces/Place0/Path = (some path
>
> HKCU/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/9.0/Open
>   Find/Places/UserDefinedPlaces/Place1/Path
>   = (another path)

**VS2008 Example:**

> HKCU/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/9.0/Open
>   Find/Places/UserDefinedPlaces/Place0/Path
>   = "C:\Dev"
>
> HKCU/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/9.0/Open
>   Find/Places/UserDefinedPlaces/Place1/Path
>   = "C:\Staging"

**Important Notes:**

- **It appears you must restart visual studio each time you edit these keys**
- VS2005 = 8.0  / VS2008 = 9.0
- Path is a String Value (REG_SZ) containing the path to be added to the places bar
- Desktop and My Computer seem to be predefined and always present?
- I don't know whether you can have more than 5 places max like (the Common dialog)
- Suggest creating a simple .REG file that can be edited and clicked to alter these

Comment: Could you include your actual reg file as an example? Mine's not working.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Open Find\Places\UserDefinedPlaces\Place0]
"Path" = "C:\\Projects\\IONOnline"

Comment: Does not work for me either. I have just tried the same technique with VS2010 (10.0), and no custom places are displayed in the Open dialogs. Too bad...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the location of "my projects", you can set the path as described for VS in the answer to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/861733cd-e337-4fce-9570-1a1d43cd64ac/

I have just done this for VS2005 and VS2008 and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I'm after. I'd like to have several places show up in the dialog.