# Customise shortcuts in Open File Dialog and Open Project Dialog

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

In the Open File Dialog and Open Project Dialog there is a short cut panel on the right. Is there any way to add our own short cuts here?
Office has a very similar dialog that allows you to do this - but Visual Studio doesn't seem to allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx) article, how to *"Customize your open file dialog"*

In StackOverflow is a thread about [VS.NET Places Bar customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237748/customizing-the-places-bar-in-visual-studio-2008).